# Storing lambdas in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I have been trying to create a dictionary with a string for each key and a lambda function for each value.  I am not sure where I am going wrong but I suspect it is either my attempt to store a lambda in a dictionary in the first place, or the fact that my lambda is using a shortcut operator.

Code:

```
dict = {
    'Applied_poison_rating_bonus': 
        (lambda target, magnitude: target.equipmentPoisonRatingBonus += magnitude)
}
```

The error being raised is `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` and pointing right at my `+=`.  Are shortcut operators not allowed in lambdas, or am I even farther off track than I thought?

For the sake of sanity, I have omitted hundreds of very similar pairs (It isn't just a tiny dictionary.)

EDIT:

It seems my issue was with trying to assign *anything* within a lambda expression.  Howver, my issue to solve is thus how can I get a method that only knows the key to this dictionary to be able to alter that field defined in my (broken) code?

Would some manner of call to eval() help?

EDIT_FINAL:

The functools.partial() method was recommended to this extended part of the question, and I believe after researching it, I will find it sufficient to solve my problem.

Comment: I just experienced a weird bug when I stored lambdas in a dictionary. Apparently, the function I was running through lambda, inexplicably, had it's parameters changed. Not sure if I can recreate this bug. I will post it if I can.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You cannot use assignments in a expression, and a `lambda` only takes an expression.

You can store lambdas in dictionaries just fine otherwise:

```
dict = {'Applied_poison_rating_bonus' : (lambda target, magnitude: target.equipmentPoisonRatingBonus + magnitude)}
```

The above `lambda` of course only returns the result, it won't alter `target.equimentPoisonRatingBonus` in-place.

Comment: Interesting, but now whatever is calling my lambda there needs to know to add the result to that particular field.  Any way around that?

Comment: @BlackVegetable: Use a proper function instead, or add a method to the `target` class.

Comment: I have about 150 of these (similar) elements in this dictionary.  Thus, using a proper function for each defeats the purpose of this dictionary.  Hmm...

Comment: @BlackVegetable: Can't you use one generic function, perhaps using `functools.partial()` to give it parameters for each dictionary entry?

Comment: I believe you more than answered this specific question.  I will look into functools.partial() more on my own.  Thank you (accepted in 5 mins).

Comment: I know the thread is old. However, using a dict constructor, you avoid those inner parentheses around the lambda. This makes the code really much nicer to read!

Comment: @avans: I was echoing the code from the OP here. The parentheses are indeed not needed.